# Execute Reader Error

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm working on a login system for C# in asp.net.  I keep getting the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code.

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


public partial class LoginPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}


protected void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//P.N
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local)\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True");//P.N
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();//P.N
    cmd.Connection = conn;//P.N


    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Usernames,Passwords FROM logininfo WHERE Usernames=@username AND Passwords=@password";//P.N
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", UsernameInput.Text);//P.N
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", PasswordInput.Text);//P.N

    conn.Open();//P.N

    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();//P.N //!!! Error is HERE!!
    string userName = "";//P.N
    string userPass = "";//P.N
    UsernameInput.Text = userName;//P.N
    PasswordInput.Text = userPass;//P.N
    while (reader.Read())//P.N
    {
        userName = reader["Usernames"].ToString();//P.N
        userPass = reader["Passwords"].ToString();//P.N
    }


    if (userName != "" && userPass != "")//P.N
    {
        Response.Write("Login Successfull");//P.N
        Session["name"] = userName;
        Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");//P.N
    }
    else {
        Error.Text = "Incorrect username/password";//P.N
    }

}
```

}

Comment: So, what does the exception say? What exactly is wrong with your SQL? Did you try to run it on the server itself using SSMS?

Comment: There should be more error info within the exception, but at a guess, since you do not specify a database as the initial catalog within your connection string, your `logininfo` table may not be in the default database for the user? It is not related to your question, but you should start making use of `using` blocks to ensure your `IDisposable` objects (SqlConnection, SqlCommand, SqlDataReader) are disposed of correctly.

Comment: @GarethD I bet that the error is about a table not found

Comment: It also looks like you are [storing passwords as plain text](http://blog.codinghorror.com/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly/), which for anything other than a homework application for learning purposes is a big no no.

Comment: This is a homework assignment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the database. Your connectionstring should look like this

```
"Data Source=(local)\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DataBaseName;Integrated Security=True"
```